# Hyphenation of "connected-component labeling"

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

[This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) refers to *connected-component labeling* and it places a hyphen between *connected* and *component*, but I think there should not be a hyphen there.

I've consulted Canada's hyphenation guide [here](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect2&info0=2#zz2) and cannot find a rule that justifies using a hyphen in this way.

I see it to be grammatically similar to something like *cracked screen repairing*, or *baked potato eating*.

Why is `connected-component` hyphenated, or is it an error?

Comment: I wrote an answer then deleted it. It's just not clear what that phrase means without more context. It does sound like a compound modifier of "labeling." Hyphenating the two words would be appropriate if they are working together and don't make sense as separate modifiers. It's the difference between a red stone house and a red-stone house: The first is make of stone and is red, the second is made of red stone.

Comment: I must say that, as it seems to me, hyphenation is in a state of anarchy.  I can find no consistency in the use or absence of hyphens.  This is despite the existence of sensible principles for their use.  We can agree, for example, that hyphenated  words in some way 'belong together' (are regularly used together in some type of context, or are intended by the writer to acquire such a connection as a concept).  But that general idea leaves enormous latitude for the differences of usage we can observe in, for example, 'week end' which for many is written as 'week-end' and for many as 'weekend'.

Comment: @Tuffy I think that the hyphenation of "weekend" is a somewhat different issue, because it is typically considered a compound. I've never heard of "connected-component" before, but I assume that it would often be considered a phrase consisting of two distinct words. For example, I don't think that many people would write it as a closed compound.

Comment: I'm sorry that the term is quite domain-specific.  It's not jargon though, in that the words have their usual meaning.  _Components_ (of an image or graph) are _connected_ if they are adjacent.  Then, each _component_ is _labeled_ with a different name or number.  I believe the whole thing should therefore just be called _connected component labeling_.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I was aware that my pet linguistic grievance might not be the best example, so I agree. I do think reason for uncertainty about hyphenation is the increased interchangeability of adjective and noun status.  My bête noire (or should it be 'bête-noire'?) is the word 'key', which was always used adjectivally (eg 'key reason') but never, till the last thirty or so years, on its own (as in "this decision is key").  I doubt there is a definitive 'right answer' to the question.  It is where professional and official publishers use 'style guides' (or is it 'style-guide's?).